# Relative homotopy

Tags: algebraic-topology

> Show, that the functions $g: S^1\to S^2$, $(x,y)\mapsto (x,y,0)$ and $h: S^1\to S^2$, $(x,y)\mapsto (x,-y, 0)$ are relative homotopies to $(1,0)\in S^1$

Hello,

I have a question to this task. I have to show, that these functions are relative homotopies to $(1,0)\in S^1$. 
We defined "relative homotopy" for subsets $A$. Therefore I guess, that this is a simpler notation for $\{(1,0)\}\subseteq S^1$.

To show, that $g,h$ are relative homotopies to $(1,0)\in S^1$, I have to give a continuous function $H:S^1\times [0,1]\to S^2$, such that

$H(-,0)=g$ and $H(-,1)=h$.

Also $g(1,0)=h(1,0)=H(1,0,t)$ with $t\in[0,1]$.

My first thought was simply $H(x,y,z)=(x, y, 0)$. 
This satisfies obviously $g(1,0)=h(1,0)=H(1,0,t)$ for every $t\in[0,1]$, but this function does not hold $H(-, 1)=h$.

So I tried to give $H$ such that it satisfies this condition first. But I can not find such an $H$.

I thought about $(x,y,z)\mapsto (x, (-1)^{\lfloor z\rfloor}y, 0)$, with $\lfloor z\rfloor=\begin{cases} 0,\quad z\in[0,1)\\ 1,\,\, \text{for}\quad z=1\end{cases}$.
But this function should not be continuous, or is it?

Else it would satisfie every condition.

Am I mistaken at any point about what I have to show, and $H$ has to satisfy?
Do you have a tip, how I can find such an $H$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can be wrong, but it seems to me that $g$ and $h$ are equal.

Comment: Anyway, any two maps $S^1\to S^2$ are homotopy relative a base point (the maps have to be based) for the easy reason that $\pi_1(S^2)=0$, which is a trivial application of Van Kampen Theorem (or cellular approximation)

Comment: Excuse me, it was a typo. I edited it. $(x,y)\mapsto (x,y,0)$. We do not know the Van Kampen Theorem yet.

Comment: MrTopology, does the homotopy work for you? If yes consider accepting it in order to close the question :) Otherwise feel free to comment and we can discuss

Comment: Hi, excuse me, that I didnt answer earlier, but I had no time to think about your homotopy yet. I am going to check the conditions now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$H \colon S^1\times I \to S^2$$ $$(x,y,t) \mapsto (x,(2t-1)y,\sqrt{y^2-(2t-1)^2y^2} )$$

Comment: This homotopy works perfectly. Such a smooth solution. $g(1,0)=h(1,0)=H(1,0,t)=(1,0,0)$ and $H(-,0)=(x,-y,0)$ and $H(-,1)=(x,y,0)$.

Comment: Would it be enough to give $H(x,y,t)=(x,(2t-1)y, 0)$. I do not see, why the t-component is rather complicated. When you calculated it, the solution for the t-component is always 0 anyways, if I am not mistaken. So, is $t\mapsto \sqrt{y^2-(2t-1)^2y^2}$" really needed, or would work "$t\mapsto 0$" aswell?

Comment: @MrTopology: $(x,(2t-1)y, 0)$ does not lie on the unit sphere.

Comment: Ah, ok. Is there an easy way to see, that $(x,(2t-1)y, \sqrt{y^2-(2t-1)^2y^2})$ always lies on the unit sphere?

Comment: @MrTopology well square all the entries, i.e. a point $x_1,x_2,x_3$ lies on the unit sphere iff $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2=1$. The square root in the third component makes sure that the equality is fulfilled

Comment: pictorially is the following. Image an half sphere lying over a plane. your homotopy is a segment on such plane (if you fix $x,y$ and let $t$ as a variable) which connects the opposite points $x,y$ and $x,-y$. The square root projects everything on the above hemisphere, so everything takes place in the sphere, since you want a map **to** the sphere.